# Trying to Authenticate the Slurm User via Keys Instead of Password Using the pam Plugin on MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

The expected behavior is for MariaDB to prompt me for a passphrase, not a password. Any help with troubleshooting would be appreciated.

```
~$ getenforce
Permissive
~$ uname -r
5.14.0-362.13.1.el9_3.x86_64
~$ mariadb -V
mariadb from 11.2.2-MariaDB, client 15.2 for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
~$ sudo mariadb -u root -e "show plugins;" | grep pam
pam     ACTIVE  AUTHENTICATION  auth_pam.so     GPL
~$ sudo cat /etc/pam.d/mariadb
#auth required pam_unix.so
#account required pam_unix.so
#auth required pam_ssh.so audit
#account required pam_ssh.so audit
auth       sufficient   pam_ssh.so debug try_first_pass
auth       include      password-auth
account    include      password-auth
~$ sudo locate pam_ssh.so
/usr/lib64/security/pam_ssh.so
~$ sudo mariadb -u root -e "show grants for 'slurm'@'%';"
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for slurm@%                                                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `slurm`@`%` IDENTIFIED VIA pam USING 'mariadb' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 20 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `slurm_acct_db`.* TO `slurm`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
~$ sudo su - slurm
Last login: Wed Dec 20 09:29:11 PST 2023 on pts/1
[slurm@hpcc ~]$ ls -l .ssh
total 8
-rw-------. 1 slurm slurm 2675 Dec 20 09:06 mariadb_rsa
-rw-------. 1 slurm slurm  583 Dec 20 09:06 mariadb_rsa.pub
[slurm@hpcc ~]$ mariadb -u slurm
[mariadb] Password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'slurm'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: What is the contents of the pam password-auth? Can this be simplified to pam_unix.so? Is this a [/etc/shadow](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-pam/#configuring-the-pam_unix-pam-module) permissions issue? Is the pam_ssh debug logs that can contribute here? If so edit the question and include them (preferably formatted).